# How to get data through audio jack in ios app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to get notifications audio jack plug in and plug out notifications but, I want to read data sent from audio jack device.

I have already tried HiJack SDK but it seems not easy. It shows lots of errors related to the supporting classes and libraries.

How can I achieve this in swift. Please suggest.

Comment: This is all handled by `AVAudioRecorder`. Have you had trouble with that? I don't know what the "HiJack SDK" is, or why you would want it over the built-in audio-recorder. See also https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/507/# which introduces the tools.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. This is not about recording or playing audio. I have a device which test blood sugar and produce its data through audio jack to Android app. I want similar functionality and app to develop for iOS.

Comment: That will still take the form of audio recording, right? You'll record the audio and convert the waveforms into data. I assume you're doing a similar thing on Android, right?

Comment: I don't know how the device works. It gets blood sample and show the suger label on the Android app. I have not developed the android app but I want to develop iOS app with same functionality. But the problem is I don't have sufficient knowledge to do the same thing using swift language.

Comment: You'll need to start by exploring how the device works. The manufacturer likely has a developer guide, though you may need to license it. It is common for manufacturers to provide an SDK (though again, these are often licensed). There is no universal standard for how to transmit data over an audio port; there are many ways to do it. All of them will take the form of "record the audio and process it to extract data." Writing this in Swift is the smallest part of the problem. The main problem is knowing the data format.